# Serializar tudo em uma única linha

Tags: c#

Estou gerando um xml de uma NFSe, porém preciso que seja gerado tudo em uma única linha, inclusive quando for gerar a assinatura. 
Quando serializo, faço desta forma:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            XmlTextWriter tw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);

            XmlSerializerNamespaces xsn = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GerarNfseEnvio));
            FileStream arquivo = new FileStream("E:\\nota.xml", FileMode.CreateNew);
            xsn.Add("", "http://www.abrasf.org.br/nfse.xsd");
            arquivo.Flush();
            ser.Serialize(arquivo, gerar, xsn);
            arquivo.Close();
```

Porém fica identado e em várias linhas, preciso tudo em uma única linha, pois a forma que estou fazendo, preciso criar um novo arquivo para cada alteração, e faço desta forma:

```
using (var writer = System.IO.File.CreateText("E:\\notasemesp.xml"))
            {
                var doc = new XmlDocument { PreserveWhitespace = false };
                doc.Load("E:\\nota.xml");
                writer.WriteLine(doc.InnerXml);
                writer.Flush();
            }
```

Só que fica inviável, criar um novo arquivo, para nova alteração, já que até o final é feito 3 alterações, então seriam necessários criar mais 3 xml, como posso corrigir este problema? 
Exemplo:
Da forma que serializo fica desta forma:

```
<Rps>
  <IdentificacaoRps>
     <Numero>1</Numero>
      <Serie>999</Serie>
      <Tipo>1</Tipo>
  </IdentificacaoRps>
 <DataEmissao>2018-11-27</DataEmissao>
<Status>1</Status>
```

Eu preciso que em cada alteração que utilizo `Save`, fique desta forma:

```
 <Rps><IdentificacaoRps><Numero>1</Numero><Serie>999</Serie><Tipo>1</Tipo</IdentificacaoRps><DataEmissao>2018-11-27</DataEmissao<Status>1</Status></Rps>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma opção é utilizar `XDocument` do `System.Xml.Linq`

```
 System.Xml.Linq.XDocument doc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load("E:\\nota.xml");
 doc.Save("E:\\notasemesp.xml", System.Xml.Linq.SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

Comment: Deu certinho, obrigado.